# Do make indexes containing another index make sense?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Given a table (id, col1, col2), does it make sense to create the following indexes:

Index1 (col1) not unique

Index2 (col1, col2) not unique

I am faced with a legacy database that is full of those.

Can I safely delete Index1? Anwser needed for SQL Server and Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can delete index 1, if you have `Index2 (col1, col2)`, there is no need for `Index1 (col1)`, drop the `Index1 (col1)`

If the query were to only need the `Index1 (col1)`, then the use of `Index2 (col1, col2)` will have a slight extra overhead because of the extra column, that is minimal to the maintenance and expense of a complete extra index.

That said, if this legacy database is running fine, why make any changes?

Comment: One reason is to cut down on pointless writes and storage due to maintaining a useless index...